# MPI complain Xcode 5 library has wrong definition

Tags: c++, macos, xcode5, mpi

I am trying to compile a package but it errors out on math.h. See below for the log file.

I am using OS X Mavericks and Xcode 5.0.1. I installed Open MPIby following [this tutorial](https://sites.google.com/site/dwhipp/tutorials/installing-open-mpi-on-mac-os-x).

`port install openmpi` is not working on OS X Mavericks temporary.

Could it be that I am missing a library or there something wrong in the compiler?

It compiles successfully on another machine. I think it has OS X 10.8 and openmpi is installed through a port on that machine.

```
Compiling TemperatureFieldToolsForComptonHeating.C
Compiling WritePhotonSources.C
Compiling hydro_rk/ModifiedBesselFunctions.C
Compiling hydro_rk/AGNDiskInitialize.C

mpic++  -c -o hydro_rk/AGNDiskInitialize.o -DLINUX -DH5_USE_16_API   -D__max_subgrids=100000 -D__max_baryons=30 -D__max_cpu_per_node=8 -D__memory_pool_size=100000 -DINITS64 -DLARGE_INTS -DCONFIG_PINT_8 -DIO_32    -DUSE_MPI   -DCONFIG_PFLOAT_8 -DCONFIG_BFLOAT_8  -DUSE_HDF5_GROUPS    -DTRANSFER   -DNEW_GRID_IO -DFAST_SIB      -DENZO_PERFORMANCE  -DSAB  -g -I/Users/tangqi/soucecode/enzo-stable/yt-x86_64/include -I/Developer/CUDA/common/inc -I/usr/local/include          -I. hydro_rk/AGNDiskInitialize.C

In file included from hydro_rk/AGNDiskInitialize.C:11:
In file included from /usr/local/include/Grid.h:62:
In file included from /usr/local/include/ovector.h:47:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/cmath:662:1: error: redefinition of 'abs' abs(double __x) _NOEXCEPT {return fabs(__x);}

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/cmath:658:1: note: previous definition is here abs(float __x) _NOEXCEPT {return fabsf(__x);}
```

...